# No classes will import from com.google.api.services

Tags: android, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've been working on OAuth2 authentication for my Android application that reads off of a Google spreadsheet, and have been wrestling with their shoddy documentation on updated APIs and such. Right now, I have the Google Java Client API and the OAuth2 API in my buildpath in order to obtain OAuth2 authorization for my app, but I'm stuck at the imports concerning, as Eclipse is telling me "The import com.google.api.services cannot be resolved":

```
com.google.api.services.oauth2.OAuth2  
com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfoplus
```

These imports are working just fine:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
```

Any help on these missing classes would be a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

need dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.9</version>
</dependency>
```